# Collection that supports filtering, sorting, eding, adding and deleting items with notification

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm

Is there some collection that is supported in Silverlight, WPF and Windows Phone, that will satisfy following criteria:

1. accepts `IEnumerable<T>` as source
2. allows filtering and sorting items
3. allows adding, editing and deleting items in filtered list
4. any changes to filtered/sorted list are reflected to source list also (I am considering filtered/sorted list only as a view to source collection)
5. any changes to filtered/sorted list will be reflected on UI control (Gridview, ListView...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an ObservableCollection.  There's really nothing else.

A variation is your own object that implements IList, but internally does whatever you want.  For that, you'd make a class that looks like this

```
class MyClass: IList, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  //implement it
}
```

**EDIT:**
There is also the [CollectionViewSource object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx)

Comment: Actually, ObservableCollection will not provide what I am after. In this particular situation, I know that data that is retrieved over network cannot be changed by anyone else, So I want to query it only once. This means that when I filter, I am creating a new collection, and I then need to sync them, filtered->original. So I need something like a CollectionView with editable capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The most versatile collection is the ObservableCollection.  You can pass it a List in the constructor.  Via LINQ you can sort and filter.   You can also sort and filter in XAML using CollectionViewSource but filtering is convoluted.  And the individual items need to implement iNotitifyPropertyChanged.  I only know WPF.

If you hide the filter behind a Public property you can force it to be reevaluated.   Might get you where you need to be.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<person> Persons = new ObservableCollection<person>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Persons.Add(new person("jim", 12));
        Persons.Add(new person("aa", 13));
        Persons.Add(new person("ff", 14));
        Persons.Add(new person("dd", 22));
        Persons.Add(new person("hky", 23));
        Persons.Add(new person("jsgdim", 24));

        List<person> YoungPersons = Persons.Where(per => per.Age < 20).ToList();
        Debug.WriteLine(Persons.Count.ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine(YoungPersons.Count.ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine(YoungPersonsProperty.Count.ToString());
        Persons[0].Name = "Jimmy";
        Debug.WriteLine(Persons[0].Name);
        Debug.WriteLine(YoungPersons[0].Name);
        Debug.WriteLine(YoungPersonsProperty[0].Name);
        Persons.Remove(Persons[0]);
        Debug.WriteLine(Persons.Count.ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine(YoungPersons.Count.ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine(YoungPersonsProperty.Count.ToString());

        string testName;
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;        
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            testName = YoungPersonsProperty[0].Name;
        }
        DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan ts = endTime - startTime;
        Debug.WriteLine(ts.Milliseconds.ToString());
    }

    public List<person> YoungPersonsProperty
    {
        get { return  Persons.Where(per => per.Age < 20).ToList(); } 
    }

    public class person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string name;
        int age;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

        public int Age { get { return age; } }
        public string Name 
        { 
            get { return name; }
            set 
            { 
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public person (string Name, int Age) 
        {
            name = Name;
            age = Age;
        }
    }
}
```

I recall getting LINQ filter to apply dynamically without hiding them behind a Property but I cannot remember how.

Comment: I already did that, but when I filter using linq, I get two separate lists, one original, and one filtered. If I remove an item from filtered, original doesnt get updated, so I need to sync them manually. See my point 4.

Comment: yes, but this is highly inefficient, you are recreating filtered collection every time a person is deleted/added. Another thing is that a control would be bound to filtered list, not list, so addingd/removing records would happen on filtered list, so synchronization would be done with persons, and not YoungPersons collection, which makes synchronization process more difficult.

Comment: Highly inefficient ??  See the timing test I ran.  1 million calls to YoungPersonsProperty in 723 milliseconds - that comes out to .000723 milliseconds per call.  And that is on a P4 desktop.  Clearly you don't understand Linq.  As for synch that is easy but I am done helping you.

Comment: There is no need to tell me that I don't understand something, even if it is true. Inefficient doesn't mean slow. Imagine you need to reload couple of hundreds of records in a grid with 10 columns, such a waste of memory and time just to add/delete 1 record. Not to mention that on delete operation you need to save a record pointer before reloading, so you can comeback where you left. Just if something is easy to do, doesn't neccesserally mean its the best way to do it.

Comment: I also never said I dont know how to syncronize two collections, I asked if there is a solution that already exists. And again, if you read my post again, you will see that the method you suggest in practice isn't possible, since you will never bind to a original collection, but to a filtered, so you will need to sync original collection, and not filtered.